# port forwarding in windows

Tags: windows, firewall, port-forwarding, windows-firewall

I need to forward all incoming traffic on specific port to another port on the same device "locally not proxy", and all outgoing port traffic.
in Linux it is possible using iptables I used NAT chains (outgoing, PREROUTING ).
but in Windows it is quite difficult because I need Kernel mode (I tried sharpPcap libraries in C# but it only captures the packet it can not stop packet and change their port "user mode"), I also tried netsh but it did not work because it works as proxy.
so I need solution in windows any idea?